# Visual Studio Code: How to create menu in view container

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating an extension in Visual Studio Code, and I'd like to know how to create a menu in my custom view container. For example, the Git Source Control extension allows you to have two folders open and click on which one to operate before performing the usual Git operations. I want to know how it is possible to create this view, and how to dynamically alter it (i.e., add/remove folders).

[image: Example of Git extension]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view

Comment: Thanks. I read the guide many times before, but I never understood it completely. Since you said the answer is there, I gave it a thorough reading this time and got what I wanted. Thank you.